# How can a I make a single string with spaces in between based on certain rules

Tags: javascript

I am encoding a set of string, on output, I want to get a single string separated by spaces like this

> "imtgdvs fearwer mayoogo anouuio ntnnlvt wttddes aohghn sseoau "

instead of

"imtgdvs"

"fearwer"

"mayoogo"

"anouuio"

"ntnnlvt"

"wttddes"

"aohghn "

"sseoau "

```
normalisedText = "ifmanwasmeanttostayonthegroundgodwouldhavegivenusroots";
const cols = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(textCount));
const rows = Math.ceil(textCount / cols);
const textArray = [];
let encodedChunks = "";
let cypherText = "";
let startIndex = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < cols; i ++) { 
  for (let j = i; j < normalisedText.length; j += cols) {
  cypherText += normalisedText[j];
  }
    cypherText += '\n';
}

console.log(cypherText);
```

Comment: what does `textCount`  contain?

Comment: Replace the `'\n'` with `' '`?

Comment: This: `cypherText += '\n'` adds a new line to the string, if you want spaces, use `cypherText += ' '`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
textCount = 5
normalisedText = "ifmanwasmeanttostayonthegroundgodwouldhavegivenusroots";
const cols = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(textCount));
const rows = Math.ceil(textCount / cols);
const textArray = [];
let encodedChunks = "";
let cypherText = "";
let startIndex = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < cols; i ++) { 
  for (let j = i; j < normalisedText.length; j += cols) {
  cypherText += normalisedText[j];
  }
    cypherText += ' ';
}

console.log(cypherText);
```